# Exchange 2016 - Unable to Send As on Mail Public Folder

Tags: email, outlook, ms-office, exchange-server, office-2016

Exchange 2016 using Outlook 2016 client

Created a new Public Folder titled

Mail-enabled the public folder:

```
Enable-MailPublicFolder -Identity "\PublicFolder"
```

Added Send As permissions.

```
Add-ADPermission PublicFolder -User domain\jsmith -Extendedrights "Send As"
```

Added permissions to receive mail.

```
Add-PublicFolderClientPermission -identity "\PublicFolder" -User Anonymous -AccessRights CreateItems
```

Set Hidden from address lists false:

```
Enable-MailPublicFolder -Identity "\PublicFolder" -HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled $False
```

The user jsmith is an owner of this public folder. He can add the public folder and the public folder can receive emails but nobody is able to "Send As" the public folder.

Under EAC I have verified that the public folder exists, permissions are in place, and the folder is mail-enabled.

I have tried disabling Mail Settings and re-enabling. I am also completely unable to select "PublicFolder" in my "From" field in OWA. It gives no option to enter a custom name and also doesn't have an option for the PublicFolder. I did add it to my Favorites.

The user receives the message "This message could not be sent. Try sending the message again later, or contact your network administrator. You do not have the permission to send the message on behalf of the specified user. Error is [0x80070005-0x0004dc-0x000524]."

The user has both Send As and Send on Behalf Of permissions.

The issue has lasted more than 24 hours so I am fairly certain that it is not a replication issue.

Comment: If there is no programming involved you could close this question and try http://serverfault.com/tour

Comment: Thank you. I have reposted on that forum.

Comment: Cross posting: http://serverfault.com/questions/803984/exchange-2016-unable-to-send-as-for-mail-public-folder

Answer (score 0):

This kind of issues might be caused by a wide range of issues:

1. Make sure that you use the correct permissions as explained in [KB 3045224](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3045224)
2. Make sure that you cleaned the client AutoCache as explained in [KB 287623](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/exchange/292-resolved-you-do-not-have-the-permission-to-send-the-message-on-behalf-of-the-specified-user.html).
3. Make sure your GAL is updated (but I would say that should be the case after the 24 hours you waited)
4. Download the OAB by hand on the affected clients
5. Try to remove the mailbox / shared folder and re-add it on the client
6. Try to remove the email address from the list (there should be a X near that) and re-add it on the client to force a recheck from the config
7. Recheck/Reset the permissions via powershell to ensure you are using the correct one
8. Check [KB 3131416](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3131416) if it apply to your environment
9. There seamed to be some issues with hidden elements in Exchange. So check out the following [URL](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook/receiving-0x80070005-0x0004dc-0x000524-error/52124cc9-33ca-4abb-a1ce-9daab808d01e) if that apply to your situation.
10. Make sure the user has only "Send As" and not additional to that "Send on Behalf Of" rights.

*More infos can be found in the [source URL](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/exchange/292-resolved-you-do-not-have-the-permission-to-send-the-message-on-behalf-of-the-specified-user.html).*

**Outcome:**

In your situation it looks like this is caused because the user has both "Send As" and "Send on Behalf Of" permissions. So please check solution 1 and fix the permission.

Answer (score 0):

After long hours of research about this issue, this is the way to solve error `0x80070005-0x0004dc-0x000524` given by a send as on public folder.

1. Delete outlook Profile
2. rename in .OLD the folder c:\users\username\appdata\roaming\outlook  or c:\users\username\appdata\roaming\microsoft\outlook
3. Create the new profile
4. If exists, Delete the autocomplete entry on field "from" with the little cross on the right.
5. Try to send

It works for me and hope it will be the same for you. 
=> Works for Exchange 2013 and Outlook 2010 & 2013.